# if possible send long press event to fire the UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I meaning simulate user long press the view, I have face a problem,

I add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer on a view, while user long press it, then it will hide , show other view which response touch event continue, but now, it does not work at all, because the long press touch event not 'end' , unless user free the screen ( release finger from screen), but I want it could be continues without the release action then continue do the touch moving operation.

hope my explain is clear, I am appreciate with your help !

thanks.